# NLog create log files based on static variable

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

How can I set NLog file name based on static variable in my application.

I have windows service that performs different tasks. Reads configuration file with task details. 
I would like to create log file based on given task name.

NOTE: class name will not work, since all the tasks call the same code.

NOTE: I am already using ${logger} variable as my current class. Since I need to know where I am as well.

-------------UPDATE--------------

Seems like this is not possible to do. 
Modified question: How to set variable values at run time?
I am talking about this:

```
<variable name="logFileName" value="" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, I believe. But you can use something like this:

In code:

```
static NLog.Logger loggerA = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("nameA");
static NLog.Logger loggerB = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("nameB");

void Something()
{
    loggerA.Error("Something");
}

void SomethingElse()
{
    loggerB.Error("SomethingElse");
}
```

NLog config:

```xml
<nlog ...>
    <targets>
        <target name="Error" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
            <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/Error.txt">
                <layout ... />
            </target>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <!--other targets pointing to different files.-->
    <rules>
        <logger name="nameA" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="Error" />
        <logger name="nameB" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Info" writeTo="Log" />-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Info" writeTo="CommonLog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

You can also use `SomeNamespace.Component.*` as name of a logger and than only logs from `SomeNamespace.Component` will be logged via it. In that case the logger would be obtained like this:

```
static NLog.Logger loggerA = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Here is the documentation for Nlog: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

There is a way to edit NLog configuration programmatically: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API

Comment: it would be useful to have ${note} that could be set at run time.
I couldn't find anything in this list here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers

Comment: @Farukh: I'm not aware of such a feature, sorry.

Comment: see updated question. 
Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @Farukh: For changing the values of the variables in NLog config see this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/694. I'm not giving exact code, because I haven't tested that. According to the latest post on the github, I'd expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to use NLog GlobalDiagnosticsContext:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${gdc:logFileName:whenEmpty=DefaultApp}.txt">
```

Then you can override it like this:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logFileName", "HelloApp");
```

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer